# OpenCV findEssentialMat() returning incorrect essential matrix

Tags: computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am experiencing an issue with cv::findEssentialMat() sometimes returning an incorrect essential matrix. What I've found is that for a specific set of point correspondences generated from an image pair, there are certain subsets (including the entire set) of these correspondences for which OpenCV's five-point algorithm converges to a dramatically different solution than the correct solution. The reason why this is strange is that every point correspondence is very similar; in other words, there are no outliers.

See attached image that visualizes how the features moved from the previous image to the current image. The blue circles indicate where the feature is in the current image, the green circles indicate where the feature was in the previous image, and the red line indicate the correspondences. All the feature correspondences are in agreement about how the camera has been shifted between images.

[image]

Here is what I have tried already without success:

- Increasing the prob parameter from 0.999 to 0.999999.
- Changing the method from RANSAC to LMEDS

I have also tried running cv::findEssentialMat() with a subset of point correspondences. This was interesting because certain subsets do result in the correct essential matrix, which is the essential matrix that encodes the following correct translation:
t ~= [-1 0 0],

But when using the whole set of point correspondences, I get this incorrect translation
t ~= [0 0 -1]

Below is a minimum working example (a cpp file, a cmake file and yaml file) demonstrating this problem. Simply run the program as

```
./test <numFeaturesToUse>
```

For example, run

```
./test 11
```

to see an example of when cv::findEssentialMat works correctly, and run

```
./test 12
```

to see an example of when it does not converge to the correct solution.
If anyone can point out what I am doing incorrectly (if anything), that would be greatly appreciated!

test.cc

```
#include <opencv2/calib3d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>

#include <iostream>


typedef std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: test.cc numFeaturesToUse" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int numFeaturesToUse = std::atoi(argv[1]); 


    // load features as cv::Mats
    cv::FileStorage inFile("../features.yaml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
    cv::Mat featuresRight_, featuresLeft_;

    inFile["featuresRight"] >> featuresRight_;

    bool loadFeaturesLeft = true;

    if (loadFeaturesLeft)
        inFile["featuresLeft"] >> featuresLeft_;
    else
    {
        // each feature in left image should be right feature shifted
        // to the right by 100 pixels. This always gets the correct
        // answer
        featuresLeft_ = featuresRight_.clone();

        cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec2f> featRightIt = featuresRight_.begin<cv::Vec2f>();
        cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec2f> featLeftIt = featuresLeft_.begin<cv::Vec2f>();
        while (featRightIt != featuresRight_.end<cv::Vec2f>())
        {
            (*featLeftIt)[0] += 100;
            (*featLeftIt)[1] += -1;

            featRightIt++;
            featLeftIt++;
        }
    }

    bool useSubset = true;
    if (useSubset)
    {        
        int startRow = 20;
        cv::Rect roi(0,startRow,1,numFeaturesToUse); // only use N rows of points starting at 
        featuresRight_ = featuresRight_(roi);
        featuresLeft_ = featuresLeft_(roi);
    }

    // perturb the feature (# 12) that is causing the problem
    // manually assign this feature to be shifted version of right feature
    // featuresLeft_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[0] += 1;
    // featuresLeft_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[1] += 1;

    // featuresRight_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[0] += -100;
    // featuresRight_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[1] += -400;
    //  featuresRight_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[0] = 400.0;
    //  featuresRight_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[1] = 400.0;

    // featuresLeft_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[0] = featuresRight_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[0] + 120;
    // featuresLeft_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[1] = featuresRight_.at<cv::Vec2f>(11)[1] - 5;

    double dsFactor = 0.7;

    cout << "Features right \n" << featuresRight_*dsFactor << "\n";
    cout << "Features left \n" << featuresLeft_*dsFactor << "\n";

    // draw the locations of left and right features on a mat
    // left - blue
    // right - gold
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("../DJI_0396.JPG");
    cv::rotate(image, image, cv::ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE);

    cv::Scalar blue(255,0,0);
    cv::Scalar green(0,255,0);
    cv::Scalar red(0,0,255);

    cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec2f> featRightIt = featuresRight_.begin<cv::Vec2f>();
    cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec2f> featLeftIt = featuresLeft_.begin<cv::Vec2f>();
    while(featLeftIt != featuresLeft_.end<cv::Vec2f>())
    {
        cv::Point2f featureLeft(*featLeftIt);
        cv::Point2f featureRight(*featRightIt);
        cv::circle(image, featureLeft, 4, blue, -1); 
        cv::circle(image, featureRight, 4, green, -1); // green
        cv::line(
            image,                        // Draw onto this image
            featureLeft,                 // Starting here
            featureRight,                 // Ending here
            red,       // This color
            1,                           // This many pixels wide
            cv::LINE_AA                  // Draw line in this style
            );

        featLeftIt++;
        featRightIt++;
    }

    cv::resize(image, image, cv::Size(), dsFactor, dsFactor);
    cv::imshow("features", image);


    // assign camera matrix
    cv::Mat cameraMatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1082.77717353143, 0, 690.835449448,
                            0,  1082.77717353143, 457.750756458,
                            0, 0, 1 );

    bool rotate = true;
    if (rotate)
    {
        double fx,fy,cx,cy;
        fx = cameraMatrix.at<double>(0,0);
        fy = cameraMatrix.at<double>(1,1);
        cx = cameraMatrix.at<double>(0,2);
        cy = cameraMatrix.at<double>(1,2);
        cameraMatrix.at<double>(0,0) = fy; 
        cameraMatrix.at<double>(1,1) = fx;
        cameraMatrix.at<double>(0,2) = cy;
        cameraMatrix.at<double>(1,2) = cx;
    }

    cout << "camera matrix = " << cameraMatrix << "\n";
    assert(featuresLeft_.size() == featuresRight_.size());

    // findEssentialMat() settings 
    double prob = 0.999;
    //int method = cv::RANSAC;
    int method = cv::LMEDS;
    //double threshold = 0.1;

    cv::Mat E = cv::findEssentialMat(featuresLeft_, featuresRight_, cameraMatrix,
                                     method, prob);

    int totalFeatures = featuresLeft_.rows;

    cout << "StereoRig::EstimatePose: Essential matrix = \n" << E << endl;
    cv::Mat R_, translation_;
    int numInliers = cv::recoverPose(E, featuresLeft_, featuresRight_, cameraMatrix,
                                     R_, translation_); // outputs

    cout << "StereoRig::EstimatePose: Number of inliers = " << numInliers << " out of " << totalFeatures << " total features" << endl;

    double percentageInliers = (double) numInliers / totalFeatures;
    double thresh = 0.6;
    if (percentageInliers < thresh)
    {
        cout << "StereoRig::EstimatePose When estimating pose from feature correspondences, percentage of inliers ("
             << percentageInliers <<") was under the threshold ("<< thresh<<")." << endl;

    }

    cout << "Estimated translation = " << "\n";
    cout << translation_ << "\n";

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0; }
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
project(test)

# link to opencv build (only look for OpenCV3 not OpenCV2)
find_package( OpenCV 3 REQUIRED)

add_executable (test test.cc)
target_link_libraries (test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

features.yaml

```
%YAML:1.0
---
featuresLeft: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 92
   cols: 1
   dt: "2f"
   data: [ 1.28847961e+02, 6.49093262e+02, 1.42563141e+02,
       6.48662964e+02, 8.19481445e+02, 1.19142212e+03, 7.20055664e+02,
       4.70487366e+02, 6.43603821e+02, 3.42356812e+02, 5.35456360e+02,
       5.23236694e+02, 1.42560211e+02, 6.48661682e+02, 4.50164185e+02,
       9.40511475e+02, 2.87309570e+02, 6.84542358e+02, 8.62315247e+02,
       1.20464592e+02, 6.15708496e+02, 2.43555664e+02, 1.30746323e+02,
       5.13080139e+02, 8.99102722e+02, 4.01146759e+02, 8.82642578e+02,
       4.15881439e+02, 5.71643616e+02, 2.78483398e+02, 6.49876892e+02,
       2.69117401e+02, 7.08090027e+02, 6.62893860e+02, 5.65718994e+02,
       4.85427002e+02, 6.91666748e+02, 7.81757141e+02, 4.73872772e+02,
       5.82393555e+02, 5.19562012e+02, 6.72122650e+01, 4.00382660e+02,
       2.22377808e+02, 5.84533264e+02, 5.59183533e+02, 8.66378845e+02,
       1.05224136e+02, 5.85873657e+02, 5.71247131e+02, 7.27359497e+02,
       5.70056396e+02, 4.35397614e+02, 5.80546875e+02, 6.60823730e+02,
       4.31280060e+02, 5.46277710e+02, 3.12825623e+02, 2.92994354e+02,
       6.69804443e+02, 3.80915070e+02, 8.45184326e+02, 5.54122681e+02,
       1.02158447e+03, 6.66822388e+02, 7.47606018e+02, 7.38320923e+02,
       8.25927917e+02, 4.38703217e+02, 1.87555298e+02, 5.21265625e+02,
       5.94745789e+02, 6.46222351e+02, 4.89565552e+02, 1.63613831e+02,
       4.85208130e+02, 6.58010864e+02, 9.67679749e+02, 6.48694763e+02,
       2.37516983e+02, 6.74387329e+02, 4.45746124e+02, 5.88605774e+02,
       5.35999390e+02, 6.20808105e+02, 2.63286713e+02, 3.44368896e+02,
       6.16288696e+02, 8.03049561e+02, 4.34126892e+02, 2.15325211e+02,
       6.25899841e+02, 3.06916382e+02, 4.56520416e+02, 4.95614868e+02,
       2.08671097e+02, 5.04676971e+02, 2.67499878e+02, 8.04450867e+02,
       2.89448669e+02, 4.97309570e+02, 9.19511292e+02, 5.60559875e+02,
       2.56943237e+02, 7.97375488e+02, 6.35597107e+02, 6.99451233e+02,
       5.04297241e+02, 5.86292419e+02, 3.40532043e+02, 2.91096863e+02,
       4.45543365e+02, 5.34794312e+02, 2.45132690e+02, 5.37259827e+02,
       1.69906967e+02, 4.61131104e+02, 9.09794434e+02, 5.24697693e+02,
       6.23089355e+02, 6.93494690e+02, 4.19500031e+02, 7.04664429e+02,
       2.68480499e+02, 5.59323608e+02, 8.14105797e+00, 7.20533752e+02,
       3.91805969e+02, 5.85539246e+02, 5.59671936e+02, 1.54184204e+02,
       5.36592224e+02, 5.88363586e+02, 5.00129486e+02, 8.33527039e+02,
       2.55457306e+01, 8.96319885e+02, 2.84405151e+02, 8.60649292e+02,
       4.74958618e+02, 5.79110352e+02, 5.90250793e+02, 7.92708252e+02,
       1.42511322e+02, 8.60564697e+02, 4.74950104e+02, 6.75626709e+02,
       3.95321686e+02, 6.55555237e+02, 9.86767151e+02, 4.55710693e+02,
       2.07409485e+02, 3.31513824e+02, 5.55117981e+02, 7.90092773e+02,
       4.63523285e+02, 1.76062378e+02, 6.18713623e+02, 6.79687073e+02,
       4.40630096e+02, 2.76415710e+02, 7.01047546e+02, 6.20903625e+02,
       8.57159729e+02, 5.22285217e+02, 5.58501221e+02, 3.54970581e+02,
       5.74421875e+02, 4.79196747e+02, 6.09657288e+02, 8.84093750e+02,
       1.07693872e+03, 6.33823853e+02, 8.33315430e+02, 2.37912460e+02,
       4.43286407e+02, 6.88389404e+02, 4.36370270e+02, 8.40665222e+02,
       3.36497498e+02, 1.77658432e+02, 5.66718872e+02, 7.55319702e+02,
       7.37769318e+00 ]
featuresRight: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 92
   cols: 1
   dt: "2f"
   data: [ 3.48587513e+00, 6.54300903e+02, 2.16347313e+01,
       6.53776978e+02, 6.97840149e+02, 1.19988525e+03, 5.98826782e+02,
       4.76740784e+02, 5.22565491e+02, 3.47719086e+02, 4.13773651e+02,
       5.28816528e+02, 2.16297665e+01, 6.53775146e+02, 3.28051147e+02,
       9.46521362e+02, 1.65979507e+02, 6.89732117e+02, 7.42543884e+02,
       1.25529305e+02, 4.94935944e+02, 2.49277206e+02, 1.01769810e+01,
       5.18613708e+02, 7.78789978e+02, 4.06911591e+02, 7.62147339e+02,
       4.21893127e+02, 4.50675201e+02, 2.84116882e+02, 5.28738892e+02,
       2.74634521e+02, 5.86458496e+02, 6.69662903e+02, 4.44102234e+02,
       4.91375946e+02, 5.69598328e+02, 7.88479553e+02, 3.52315247e+02,
       5.88038025e+02, 3.99272858e+02, 7.24335175e+01, 2.79831665e+02,
       2.27995819e+02, 4.62965271e+02, 5.65336975e+02, 747., 110., 464.,
       577., 6.05831604e+02, 5.76349426e+02, 3.13826538e+02,
       5.86211914e+02, 5.39379211e+02, 4.37007294e+02, 4.25307678e+02,
       3.18409332e+02, 1.71548569e+02, 6.75439392e+02, 2.59090179e+02,
       8.50806824e+02, 4.32000031e+02, 1.02846155e+03, 5.44752502e+02,
       7.53849792e+02, 6.16563049e+02, 8.33063477e+02, 3.18476013e+02,
       1.92946686e+02, 3.99383270e+02, 6.00583191e+02, 5.24528076e+02,
       4.95570587e+02, 4.31030235e+01, 4.90446259e+02, 5.36113647e+02,
       9.74736084e+02, 5.28095642e+02, 2.43140930e+02, 5.53183777e+02,
       4.52007416e+02, 4.66995789e+02, 5.41647949e+02, 4.99978821e+02,
       2.68422241e+02, 223., 622., 6.82151550e+02, 4.39999298e+02,
       9.44022217e+01, 6.31038269e+02, 186., 462., 3.75099762e+02,
       2.14107742e+02, 3.83958862e+02, 2.73195770e+02, 6.83860474e+02,
       2.95132202e+02, 3.75323700e+02, 9.25819702e+02, 4.40014893e+02,
       2.62267639e+02, 6.75859680e+02, 6.42131897e+02, 5.78106018e+02,
       5.10620270e+02, 4.65280518e+02, 3.46075043e+02, 1.70320724e+02,
       4.50776031e+02, 4.13994263e+02, 2.50434418e+02, 417., 175.,
       3.39066467e+02, 9.16131042e+02, 4.02902557e+02, 6.29403015e+02,
       5.72313904e+02, 4.25308411e+02, 5.84261230e+02, 2.73812378e+02,
       4.39524597e+02, 1.32251701e+01, 5.99402161e+02, 3.97848175e+02,
       4.63748627e+02, 5.65522583e+02, 3.37356911e+01, 5.41680481e+02,
       4.66630371e+02, 5.05906525e+02, 714., 30., 7.76105896e+02,
       2.89903259e+02, 7.40108154e+02, 4.80904846e+02, 4.57319580e+02,
       5.96026062e+02, 673., 148., 7.40087891e+02, 4.81301239e+02,
       5.54387695e+02, 4.01024597e+02, 5.33782959e+02, 9.94106750e+02,
       3.35050629e+02, 2.12548187e+02, 2.10056046e+02, 5.60611633e+02,
       6.69055542e+02, 4.69386414e+02, 5.54003754e+01, 6.23763367e+02,
       5.58282837e+02, 4.46638702e+02, 1.54980133e+02, 7.06359802e+02,
       4.98765839e+02, 8.63861084e+02, 4.00624634e+02, 5.64329407e+02,
       2.33481201e+02, 5.79876953e+02, 3.57501984e+02, 6.15616211e+02,
       7.62703003e+02, 1.08548193e+03, 5.11708618e+02, 8.40311646e+02,
       1.17268921e+02, 4.48423584e+02, 5.66531982e+02, 4.42379242e+02,
       7.20351318e+02, 3.42316284e+02, 57., 572., 6.35811890e+02,
       1.21897068e+01 ]
```

Comment: Hello @GuiltySpark, how did you solve the problem? I am having similar issue. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was never able to solve this but moved on eventually. It may just be a bug in that version of OpenCV. Try using OpenCV4 and see if that fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please post your solution here if you ever find out? I will do the same.